# ¿Cómo saber si el título de un cpt creado coincide con algún cpt existente?

Tags: php, wordpress, funciones

Necesito comparar el nombre de un post de reciente creación, contra la lista de otro tipo de cpt ya creados.

Tengo un CPT llamado "cuponeras", y un CPT llamado "empresariales", cuyos nombres son idénticos a un cupón que se le da al usuario. Ese cupón se le hace llegar al usuario para hacer uso de ciertas partes del sitio.

Si el usuario utiliza su cupón, se crea un cpt "empresariales" con el nombre del cupón.

Entonces con este código quiero verificar primero, si existe ese cupón en la lista del cpt-cuponeras. Y si existe, hacer una posterior verificación de si se ha creado o no un cpt-empresariales con el mismo nombre.

El problema es que la variable **$codigo_de_cupon_es_valido** siempre permanece en **no**. El código es el siguiente:

```
// Checo si el cupón es válido
        global $post;
        $codigo_de_cupon = $_POST['codigo_de_cupon'];
        $codigo_de_cupon_es_valido = 'no';
        $codigo_de_cupon_msg = 'Tu código "' . $codigo_de_cupon . '" no es válido.';

        $cupones_existentes = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'   => 'cuponeras'
        ) );
        $empresariales_creados = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'   => 'empresariales'
        ) );

        // Ahora reviso cada uno de los cupones existentes, y lo comparo contra el código insertado por el usuario.
        foreach ($cupones_existentes as $cupon_existente) {
            $cupon_existente = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name', true );
            
            if ( $cupon_existente == $codigo_de_cupon ):
            
                foreach ($empresariales_creados as $empresarial_creado) {

                    $empresarial_creado = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name', true );

                   if ( $empresarial_creado != $codigo_de_cupon ):
                        $codigo_de_cupon_es_valido = 'si';
                        $codigo_de_cupon_msg = 'Esperamos que disfrutes tu regalo';
                  endif;

                }  // foreach ($empresariales_creados as $empresarial_creado)

            endif;
            
        }  // foreach ($cupones_existentes as $cupon_existente)
    
    
        // Si el código de cupón es válido, verifica errores. Si no es válido, avisa que no es válido.
        if( $codigo_de_cupon_es_valido == 'si' ):
```

// Aquí continúa el resto del código

La variable **$codigo_de_cupon_es_valido** siempre permanece en **no**.

No tengo gran experiencia programando, no se si estoy utilizando bien las funciones, o si en lugar de get_post es wpQuery...

Gracias por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, recibí asesoría de un profesional que me mostró la función **get_page_by_title();**

Y me ayudó a pulir el código hasta llegar a esto:

```
    $codigo_de_cupon = $_POST['codigo_de_cupon'];
    $codigo_de_cupon = sanitize_text_field($_POST['codigo_de_cupon']);
    $codigo_de_cupon_es_valido = 'si';
    $codigo_de_cupon_msg = 'Todo bien';
    $titulo_del_cupon = '';
    $cupon_a_eliminar = '';

    $existe_cupon_en_cuponera = FALSE;
    $prueba_cuponeras = get_page_by_title($codigo_de_cupon, OBJECT, 'cuponeras');
    $prueba_cupones_usados = '';

    if( $prueba_cuponeras == null ):
        $existe_cupon_en_cuponera = FALSE;
    else:
        $existe_cupon_en_cuponera = TRUE;
        $codigo_de_cupon_es_valido = 'si';
        $codigo_de_cupon_msg = 'Esperamos que disfrutes tu regalo.';
    endif;

    if( $existe_cupon_en_cuponera == TRUE ):
        $prueba_cupones_usados = get_page_by_title($codigo_de_cupon, OBJECT, 'empresariales');
        if( $prueba_cupones_usados != null ):
            $codigo_de_cupon_es_valido = 'no';
            $codigo_de_cupon_msg = 'Tu código ' . $codigo_de_cupon . ' no es válido.';
            $cupon_a_eliminar = $prueba_cuponeras->ID;
        endif;
    endif;
```

Y el código funciona muy bien.